# No Internet connection wireless or wired

Tags: internet

I can't connect to the Internet via wireless network or Ethernet
I can connect to the router, but when I launch Firefox, it tells me I can't connect to the server

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping an IP-address to see if it is a DNS problem:

```
ping -c4 173.194.40.51
```

If this does'nt work, please edit your question to contain output from these commands: `lspci` and `ifconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Step One: Determine your gateway (router) address

Open a terminal and issue the command `route -n`

Note that my interface is wlan0 as I'm currently connected via wireless, yours will likely be eth0

[image: gw]

Step Two: Insure that you can ping the router

issue the command `ping -c4 *gateway address* (in my case it is 192.168.15.254)

You should have 0% packet loss. Failure here indicates trouble communicating with your router (the problem is likely bad cabling or a bad port on the router)

Step Three: Try to ping an address by name on the internet for example:

`ping -c4 google.com` again we are hoping to see 0% packet loss

If this fails you likely have a DNS problem. Below you'll see an example of what happens if you ping a known address followed by an unknown (non-existent) address.

[image: DNS]

You can confirm a DNS problem by pinging a known address by number for instance google.com at 173.194.46.68 like `ping -c4 173.194.46.68` If the name fails and the number doesn't the problem is with DNS.

If pinging by number also fails you have a problem somewhere down the line (probably outside your premises) and may wish to contact your ISP.

You can get the adresses for your ISP gateway and DNS Servers out of your router (methods vary slightly by manufacturer/model - consult your manual) pinging those may allow you to converse a bit more intelligently with your ISP Perhaps assisting them in assisting you!.